# Jquery function - Prevent click the same button more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("[id*='button_insert']").click();
$("[id*='button_insert_movement']").click();
```

I use this function to click on multiple buttons with the same id at the same time.

It happens that some clicks are repeated. How can I prevent pressing the same button more than once?

I try use `.one('click')` and `.stopPropagation();` but only click in first button.

is the same use `$('#button_insert').click();`

Comment: ids are unique, you can't have multiple buttons/elements with the same id. Use a class for that purpose

Comment: In addition to the main problem of using `IDs` instead of `classes` or better still `data-attributes` is that using `*=` also selects the second button since it has a similar name.

Comment: @ChrisG is the same button but per line, inside for loop. What you recommend add a counter in id?

Comment: @Miguel you could use a `class` or `data-attribute` as mentioned in the previous comments. If your button is created inside a loop, adding a counter could also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will add inside the click event, check if the button has already been clicked by checking if it has the 'clicked' class.

If the button has not been clicked before, we add the 'clicked' class to the button using. This class is used to keep track of the clicked state of the button.

We also disable the button using $(this).prop('disabled', true) to prevent any further clicks. This ensures that the user can only click the button once.

#### Try below code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id*='button_insert']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('clicked once');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_insert">Click me</button>
```